# Android Studio running Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried running an android studio app on an android device and it doesn't seem to be working. The run window said:

```
04/11 08:29:55: Launching app
$ adb push /Users/kids/AndroidStudioProjects/Calculator/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.piggyinc.calculator
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK
```

Could anyone help me? By the way it is correct api level. I chose 4.0.3 and this device is like a 5.1

Comment: you can see a dialog confirmation in your device?

Comment: no. I cannot see  a dialog confirmation

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have the USB debugging turned on. when you plug the device to the computer the phone will ask you to allow debugging

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't enabled developer options for your device. Try following these steps in the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/device.html#developer-device-options):

> Android-powered devices have a host of developer options that you can
>   access on the phone, which let you:
>
> Enable debugging over USB. Quickly capture bug reports onto the
>   device. Show CPU usage on screen. Draw debugging information on screen
>   such as layout bounds, updates on GPU views and hardware layers, and
>   other information. Plus many more options to simulate app stresses or
>   enable debugging options. To access these settings, open the Developer
>   options in the system Settings. **On Android 4.2 and higher, the
>   Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go
>   to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to
>   the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.**

Once you have done this, go into the developer options (which should now be available in Settings) and make sure you enable the option "USB debugging." Then disconnect your device from USB, and plug it back in. A dialog should appear asking you to allow this computer to use it for debugging. Allow this, and then you should be good to go for running builds on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Delete authorized devices inside Developer Options in Settings, and try to reconnect the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but if you have already enabled USB debuggind,then it doesn't work
All you have to do is to uncheck USB debugging and then you check it again so that it will appear the message box inviting you to validate the new device